# Distributed 1.21.8 requires msgpack

Tags: python, anaconda, google-earth

I'm trying to install google earth engine python API on my pc. 
During installation process i received this error message "distributed 1.21.8 requires msgpack, which is not installed". I looked for the different possilities to install this package but, it didn't function. 
How can I do?
My pc is windows and I used Anaconda

thanks so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. Try this here:  `pip install msgpack`